# Radius of convergence of $ f(z)=\frac{z^2} {e^z+1} $ without expansion

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to find the radius of convergence of $ f(z)=\frac{z^2} {e^z+1} $ w.r.t $0$  without using Taylor's expansion.

My work, $f(z)$ has poles at $z=(2k+1)i\pi,k \in \mathbb Z$, so the poles nearest to $0$ are $i\pi$ ot $-i\pi$, and the distance from origin is $\pi$, so is the radius of convergence. Is it true?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. $$ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $$

Comment: maybe better  to write it as comment?

Comment: @dato I wrote it as an answer so it doesn't appear on the question lists as unanswered. Also, I like getting reputation points and don't care how I get them.

Comment: sure  ok no problem,i have gave  +1.no problem my friend

Comment: @Mathematician No, please do. That gets me 15 rep!

Comment: @Mathematician  if you need additional hints,just edit your question

Comment: i think it is 25 right?or 15?

Comment: @dato 15 rep for an accepted answer, 10 for an upvote. So if OP is cool and upvotes as well as accepts, its 25.